# Azure AD B2C: Cannot disable federated accounts

Tags: azure, entra-id

In an Active Directory B2C Tenant, all users that have a federated identity only are shown in the Azure Portal as "Enabled: No". Still, they can sign in. Also, changing the property using the Azure Portal has no effect. Why is that? The [user profile attributes documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-profile-attributes) describes the property as "Whether the user account is enabled or disabled".

There is [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63599125/azure-ad-b2c-disable-block-sign-in-for-social-federated-users) on stackoverflow, but it only says that disabling is not possible -- not why it is not possible.